# How to work with Twig files in a (vs the original html files)

Tags: html, svn, symfony, twig

I've got an internal developer that's going to be working with the design in my production setting. What I'm doing right now is storing the original design files in a separate repo, and then storing the design-impl (the Twig files) inside the repo where my app resides. This is causing a headache when it comes to fixing bugs in the design and what not.

What I want to know, is - is it better for us to now abandon the original HTML files (that are agnostic to symfony2) since we have Twig templates made? It's becoming quite a headache to fix HTML and CSS bugs now that we've got both implemented. But I thought I heard somewhere that it was best to totally separate design from implementation. I wasn't sure if this meant to go as far as to have the pure design stored in a separate repo.

Any thoughts on this? How do some of you do this in your dev environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We faced similar problem once. We had separate design in pure html before, but as you mentioned - fixing bugs in both versions is a headache. And the real problems begin when your versions start to diverge (a developer forgot to update design files, for instance)... As result - we taught our designer to work with twig, less and whatever was needed **within** our application.

You could also implement a test design environment with mocked controllers that would return all possible data combinations, create separate routes for them, etc but make them use the same CSS/HTML (less, twig, whatever)

Comment: I like the way you think